# Предлог в или на?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

> Сдать экзамен на(в) следующем семестре.

Я использую "на", а меня исправили на "в". Верно ли это, и стоит ли за этим какая-то логика? Это мне к каким словарям обращаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За употреблением предлога "**в**" стоит простейшая логика: семестр - **временной период**, *учебное полугодие* (в буквальном переводе - шесть месяцев). Предлог "*на*" сочетается разве что с *неделей*, но не с месяцами, годами или его частями (четвертью, полугодием). "*В этом семестре*" - то же, что "*в этом* (учебном) *полугодии*".